# Why is every single HTML tag being stripped out of liveblog entries?

Tags: plugins, html, the-content, html-editor, post-content

I have variously been using Livepress and the Automattic/Wordpress VIP Liveblog plugin as a live-blogging solution.

However, I have run into an issue that does not seem specific to either plugin but something that must be happening as a result of something else in Wordpress, and I don't even know where to begin.

Essentially, even when I use the text/HTML editor in both of these solutions – without switching to the visual editor – the resulting post is completely devoid of even basic HTML tags. So it will strip out the tags from `<em>text</em>` so the output is just `text`. It will strip out `<img>` tags completely. Essentially, anything that is not plain text gets removed from `the_content`.

This issue is *not* happening in the normal post editor.

It looks like a `wp_strip_all_tags` is being applied somewhere, but I can't fathom for a second where it's happening. I initially thought it was a TinyMCE issue, but I have since added a function to my functions.php which allows all elements and it has not resolved the issue.

Where should I begin looking for the solution to this, given the issue happens across two different plugins? I had successfully used Livepress in the past, but it seems that recent Wordpress updates and subsequent issues are causing this interaction to happen.

Comment: Possibly something to do with user permissions? https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html

Comment: @WebElaine It could be. Where would I check? It's not a Wordpress MU set-up, but could some plugin be enforcing this on users? I've installed [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/unfiltered-mu/) in the hopes that it might force a resolution, but it hasn't fixed things...

Comment: For non-admin roles, I would try installing the free version of User Role Editor and checking each role to see whether the unfiltered_html permission is checked for them. If not, check the box and try again (and you can safely remove URE - the permissions will be saved whether you keep the plugin or not).

Comment: @WebElaine Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the issue – both admin and editor users have that box checked. Do you have any other thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Afraid not. I'd contact the plugin authors.